# SP2013 SOAP uri scheme not valid

Tags: claims-based-auth, soap

I want to connect to SharePont through SOAP and Claims authentification. When I try my code I got the message:

> URI scheme 'http' give is not valid ; Scheme 'https' was expected.

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
           <basicHttpBinding>
              <binding name="ListsSoap">
                <security mode="Transport">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
                </security>
              </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>

          <endpoint address="http://mysharepointAdress/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ListsSoap"
              contract="ListService.ListsSoap" name="ListsSoap"/>
        </client>

      </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Code:

```
       const string listName = "myList";

        var query = new XElement("Query", "");
        var viewFields = new XElement("ViewFields", "");
        var queryOptions = new XElement("QueryOptions", "");

        var client = new ListService.ListsSoapClient();
        //client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("appes", "PWD");
        var result = client.GetListItems(listName, null, query, viewFields, null, queryOptions, null);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

How can I use http instead of https to get data from my site ?

Edit: Just for informations. I didn't know why I can't use http with SOAP, so I use the Rest API. It work very well !

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest that you use https for authentication using oauth on a live system. However if it is a development machine, you can configure it to use http.

You have to update the settings of the security token service (STS). The powershell script below should help you do that.

```
$c = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig

$c.AllowMetadataOverHttp = $true

$c.AllowOAuthOverHttp= $true

$c.Update()
```

I would also suggest you read the following article:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/07/23/setting-up-an-oauth-trust-between-farms-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: In the production farm i can use https but not in the dev farm. I don't need to communicate between two farms, should i follow the article anyway ? I try the powershell snippet but i have the same error when i try my code.

Comment: @Sancho Yes. Please run the powershell script. You still need to configure the STS to allow authentication and metadata over http.

Comment: Already run but didn't change anything

Comment: @Sancho you might have to do an IISReset.

Comment: I restart iis with iisreset.exe, service manager and i try with a server reboot. But still have the error message.

Comment: @Sancho ah.. It will be because you have selected the security mode as transport which defaults to https. You need to change that. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481131/what-are-the-differences-between-security-mode-transport-and-security-mode-tr) has more details

Comment: I change my security.mode by Message and transport.clientCredentialType by Windows. I got the message: BasicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType is not equal to  BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate for the secure messages select TransportWithMessageCredential or Transport to transport identification informations UserName. If i choose TransportCredentialsOnly, i got the same message with https/http.